# add two drawable into EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, drawable

i put a drawable in a EditText with this code:

```
    final Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.del2);
    x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
    atxt.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, x, null);
```

when i want to put another one, The first drawable disappear !! i want to put two drawable but apparently this is not possible! is there anyway?

Comment: i think you should create your own EditText ( Custom View)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `atxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (x, null, x, null);` instead

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for LayerDrawable.
More information with some samples can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Hope, it will help.